# Order of execution in a recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

When a return command has two recursive calls such as 
`return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);`, are both calls executed at the same time, or is `fib(n-1)` executed before `fib(n-2)`?

By using memoization the time complexity reduces to O(n), but isn't it possible only if `fib(n-1)` is executed before `fib(n-2)` (to then use stored values)?

*`public int fib(int n)` is a method that calculates the Nth Fibonacci number using recursion.

Comment: Order of evaluation is LTR. Doesn't matter for memoization; either the value is present in the cache or it is not. Hint: what does `fib(n-1)` call next? Also, memoization to solve Fibonacci is slow, inefficient, overly complicated and for many other reasons a Bad Idea TM.

Comment: What is LTR? For the value to be present it has to be calculated beforehand, though (as fib(n-1) calls fib(n-2), when memoization is used and fib(n-2) is not calculated again). I am trying to solve it this way, because I am practicing dynamic programming and any other question seems too difficult/vague for implementation for me right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java [guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) that the order of evaluation of sub-expressions in an expression is left-to-right.

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific *evaluation order*, namely, from left to right.

This means that `fib(n-1)` will be evaluated before `fib(n-2)`.

But the evaluation order doesn't change the complexity of memoization here, it's still O(n) either way.  As Java evaluates it, `fib(n-1)` will complete all memo values through `n-1`, including the value for `fib(n-2)`.  The call to `fib(n-2)` doesn't do any work; it just references the value `fib(n-1)` already calculated.

If you reversed the order in the code:

```
fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Then `fib(n-2)` would be called first, which would complete all memo values through `n-2`.  Then the call to `fib(n-1)` would use the existing memoized values to "finish the job" of completing all values through `fib(n-1)`.

Either way, after evaluating these expressions, all values through `n-1` are memoized, with a (worst-case) time complexity (and space complexity) of O(n).  Also presumably this is the result of calling `fib(n)`, which would additionally memoize the value for `n`.